# Rails 4, migration to change datatype of column from daterange to tsrange causing PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, range, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to change a column of type daterange to tsrange (I realized I need time as well as date) using a vanilla Rails migration

```
def self.up
  change_column :events, :when, :tsrange
end
```

After running `rake db:migrate` the error is

`PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "when" cannot be cast automatically to type tsrange
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
: ALTER TABLE "events" ALTER COLUMN "when" TYPE tsrange`

I tried following the hint and used the following

```
def self.up
  change_column :events, :when, :tsrange, 'tsrange USING CAST(when AS tsrange)'
end
```

but then got

`no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

From what I can tell, USING CAST is mainly meant for use with ints.  Assuming I don't want to drop and then recreate the column, what do you have to specify to alter the type from daterange to tsrange?

I'm using

- Rails 4.0.1
- ruby-2.0.0-p247
- psql (9.2.4)

Some background, daterange and tsrange were introduced to Rails 4 in the following PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7345.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [USING clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) is used to specify how to convert the old values to the new ones:

> The optional `USING` clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data type to new. A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

So USING shows up any time there is no default cast from the old type to the new type. Also note that USING is specified as `USING expression` so any expression (whose value is of the correct type) can be used with a USING, the most common is `USING CAST(...)` but the `expression` can be pretty much anything.

Hopefully that should clear up some confusion about USING.

So what's up with the ActiveRecord error? Well, [`change_column`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column) is expecting to see an `options` Hash in the fourth argument but you're sending in a string. If you look at the `change_column` source, you'll see things like `options[:limit]` but [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) expects integer arguments so your string argument is triggering odd looking complains about Symbols.

AFAIK there is no way to get AR to add a USING clause to the `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` that `change_column` generates. This leaves `connection.execute(some_sql)` if you need a USING clause. Of course this is further complicated by the (apparent) lack of a built-in cast from `daterange` to `tsrange` but building the necessary expression isn't terribly difficult if you pull the `daterange` apart with the [`upper` and `lower`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) functions:

```
connection.execute(%q{
  alter table events
  alter column "when"
  type tsrange using tsrange(lower("when"), upper("when"))
})
```

You can see the table change in action over here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fb047/2

That assumes that you're using the default half-open intervals (`[...)`) for your ranges; if you have ranges that aren't closed on the left and open on the right then you'll have to build a more complicated USING expression using the [other range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to see if the left and right ends of the ranges are open or closed.

---

BTW, `when` is a [PostgreSQL keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) so it isn't the best choice for an identifier, you'll have to say `"when"` every time you refer to that column in SQL snippets and that might get tiring. I'd recommend using a different name for that column so that you don't have to worry about quoting.